# Hash data being altered when sent to class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My endpoint sends `params` to a class/worker.

```
def end_point
  SomeClass.new.perform(params)
end
```

`SomeClass` starts defining variables.

```
def perform(params)
  @variable = params[:variable]
end
```

If I do `@variable.count` in a pry session, it will return `2`. But if I do `params[:variable].count`, it returns `1`(the correct value). The data is being altered from within the method.

I tried renaming the arguments from `params`, I tried setting the variable in pry manually (this will result in `1`), but when it is defined inside the method, it still results in `2`. I inspected to make sure nothing is being altered sending from the controller. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
params

    {"variable"=>
      [{"id"=>68,
        "ed"=>5213,
        "lo_id"=>2192,
        "lo_name"=>"Arkan",
        "state"=>"created",
        "closed_at"=>nil,
        "unstarted"=>false,
        "crtal"=>0,
        "cas_eived"=>0,
        "or_payments"=>0,
        "cips"=>0,
        "g_sles"=>0,
        "ters"=>0,
        "itews"=>
         [{"id"=>615,
           "unit_re"=>{"id"=>708, "name"=>"each", "abbreviation"=>"ea", "quantity"=>"1.0", "stock_item_id"=>985, "default_for"=>["base"]},
           "pce"=>0,
           "nme"=>"1 Yer nant",
           "sol]unt"=>0,
           "cgory_id"=>nil,
           "caty_name"=>"Uncategorized",
           "sub_rows"=>nil,
           "prev_count"=>0,
           "preransfunt"=>0,
           "pre_nt"=>0,
           "staount"=>0,
           "actrt_count"=>0,
           "id_evecount"=>0,
           "minsfers_out_ount"=>0,
           "wasunt"=>0,
           "grunt"=>0,
           "ennt"=>0,
           "ovunt"=>0,
           "gont"=>0,
           "quane"=>1,
           "expunt"=>0,
           "goes"=>0,
           "staiance"=>0,
           "vance"=>0,
           "paramsToConvert"=>
            ["scount",
             "pent_transfer_in_count",
             "pent_transfer_out_count",
             "s_end_count",
             "o_count",
             "e_count",
             "g_count",
             "a_start_count",
             "m_transfers_in_count",
             "m_transfers_out_count",
             "g_count",
             "w_count",
             "s_count"]},
    "action"=>"batch_print",
     "controller"=>"s",
     "event_id"=>"53",
     "format"=>"pdf"
    }
```

Comment: Can  you share a sample value of `params`?

Comment: yes be prepared though, its very long

Comment: What is the class of `params` and `params[:variable]`?

Comment: added some example params.

Comment: Have you change `params` into `options` and see what's going on?

Comment: What do you mean changing into options?

Comment: The sample shared by you does not compile, I think issue is somewhere else - not in the code that you have shared above - it works fine for sample inputs that I created

Comment: That's why I was saying this is super weird behavior

Comment: The params you provide are incomplete. Can you please correct or add plain json params?

Comment: Ya I will. Can't at the moment